# How to display the text under the basic.rect element which is having halo handlers using joint js or rappid js

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

I have tried by giving the below properties but it did not work.

```
obj.attrs.text["ref"] = 'rect';
obj.attrs.text["ref-dx"] = .5;
obj.attrs.text["ref-y"] = 0;
obj.attrs.text["x-alignment"] = "middle";
obj.attrs.text["y-alignment"] = "middle";
```

I am using svg markup which is a rect but when i change the above properties the halo handlers are also getting affected, without effecting the halo handlers how to display the text beneath the sv markup

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a new Stencil shape of type: `basic.Circle` :

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
        size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
        attrs: {
            circle: { width: 50, height: 30, fill: '#602320' },
            text: { text: 'START', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
        }
    })
```

then you can set some attributes according to the JSON structure that you have to gain access to.

For example by setting:

```
cell.attr('text/text', 'My sample text');
```

You can have the following change to this shape:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Circle({
        size: { width: 5, height: 3 },
        attrs: {
            circle: { width: 50, height: 30, fill: '#602320' },
            text: { text: 'My sample text', fill: '#ffffff', 'font-size': 10, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 0 }
        }
    })
```

You can also change the first JSON level of a shape by setting:

```
cell.set('some_first_level_attribute', 'value of some_first_level_attribute');
```

Try to `console.log` your `cell` in order to see and understand the exact JSON format of every single cell you want to set.

A typical JSON of a cell can be the following one:

```
{
    "type": "basic.Circle",
    "size": {
        "width": 85,
        "height": 51
    },
    "position": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 340
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "b3810f0f-00e1-4fde-a448-0966da71e285",
    "embeds": "",
    "z": 1,
    "attrs": {
        "circle": {
            "fill": "#602320",
            "width": 50,
            "height": 30,
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-dasharray": "0"
        },
        "text": {
            "font-size": 10,
            "text": "My sample text",
            "fill": "#ffffff",
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "stroke": "#000000",
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "font-weight": 400
        }
    }
}
```